# How to populate mysql database by tweaking existing data

Tags: mysql, database

Need to populate database with more than 80k entries.So , I am selecting my existing database and appending 1 to id(primary key).This isn't working , please help.

```
INSERT INTO `products`(`id`, `Code`, `Product_name`, `Pack`, `MRP`, `VPTR`) 
VALUES(
SELECT( CONCAT(`id`,'1') , `Code`, `Product_name`, `Pack`, `MRP`, `VPTR`) FROM `products`)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When inserting a `SELECT`ed dataset, you do not use the `VALUES` keyword. Your statement should be:

```
INSERT INTO `products`(`id`, `Code`, `Product_name`, `Pack`, `MRP`, `VPTR`) 
SELECT  CONCAT(`id`,'1') , `Code`, `Product_name`, `Pack`, `MRP`, `VPTR` 
FROM `products`
```

Comment: Its working, can u help with preventing duplicate id created due to appending 1, because 1 append to 1 will 11 which already exists.

Comment: That would be a separate question and solutions may or may not be simple. I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: I guess turing id to auto increment and appending id with code would help.

Comment: Yes or if id is numeric you could save the current `MAX(id)` into a variable and `SELECT @maxid + `id`, Code, ...`. Since you're concatenating though I assumed it was a varchar and not numeric

Comment: If it were auto increment you could get away with not specifying the column `id` at all.